# How do I set a function property on a dynamic COM object?

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, com, ole

I am looking at Amibroker's OLE documentation examples in VBScript and JS trying to convert it to C# code:
http://www.amibroker.de/guide/objects.html

In it it says:

```
Filter( 0, "index" ) = 1; // include only indices
Filter( 1, "market" ) = 2; // exclude 2nd market
```

I have a C# dynamic object that I built, and I can find and call the Filter() function, but I have no idea how to set the value after the function call, since that is not valid C# syntax.

Here is the C# code:

```
var type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Broker.Application");
dynamic ab = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
ab.Analysis.Filter(0, "market") = 2; // This is obviously not compiling
```

When I call ab.Analysis.Filter(0, "market"), it simply returns an int for the current setting. Is the answer to use reflection somehow? I haven't tried to go down that route wondering if there is a simpler solution.

Comment: I am still curious if there is a purely C# answer to this, but I turned to a VB function to do the trick: 

    
    Public Shared Sub SetFilter(ab As Object, type As Int32, category As String, value As Int32)
        ab.Analysis.Filter(type, category) = value
    End Sub

Comment: Anything the you can do in VB.NET you should be able to accomplish in C#.  VB.NET is more liberal in parsing dynamic objects, but it still can be accomplished in C#.   VB.NET will accept more late binding than C#.  C# you can use 'var' to get work similar to vb.net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code snippet you found is jscript, not VBScript.  It is not a function property, it is an *indexed* property.  VB.NET supports them well.  But the C# team did not like them and only permits one indexed property for a class, the indexer (this[]).  By popular demand they added support in version 4.  Only for COM interop.  Which is what you are using.

Just like the indexer, you use square brackets for indexed properties:

```
 AA.Filter[0, "market"] = 1;
```

Which should be supported by *dynamic* as well.  Explicitly calling the setter function would be another way, AA.set_Filter(0, "market", 1).

Note that you'll have a *much* easier time writing this code when you add a reference to the type library.  That lights up IntelliSense and the red squiggles.